# Having an issue with iterating output to a certain way

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration

I am practicing using arrays and iteration in Ruby. I was able to understand the context of the code but I am having a problem displaying the output a certain way.

My expected output is:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

The current output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
```

My code is:

```
class Image
  def initialize(image)
    @image = image
  end

  def output_image
    @image.each_index do |array|
      subarray = @image[array]
      subarray.each do |cell|
        if array[0]
          print "#{cell} \n"
        elsif array[1]
          print "#{cell} \n"
        elsif array[2]
          print "#{cell} \n"
        elsif array[3]
          print "#{cell} \n"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
 ])

 image.output_image
```

Comment: It's not necessary for you to beg us for help. That's the goal of the site. Your use of `print "... \n"` is the problem. `\n` forces your output to start a new line after each print.

Comment: I understand your point but I came for help after struggling for 10 hours on this. I use this website as the last line of defense

Comment: That may be. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a discussion list, it's more like an online reference book. Your question started a new article to help future users, and, as a result, the wording should be detailed and to the point. It can be somewhat informal, and while answers to the question help you SO is not a personal help site, so pleas for help don't fit. The goal is to help others primarily.

Comment: Yep. You are right about that. I should've have write out explicitiy on what I was struggling on. I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this unnecessarily complicated for you I think. You can just iterate over the sub arrays and join them with a space.

```
def output_image
  @image.each do |image|
    puts image.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: Much cleaner! I think it should be `puts` though, so that each subarray is printed on its own line.

Comment: @JustinHellreich Yes, updated to use `puts` instead, good point.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I wasn't thinking of join method. I am going to go over on array document again.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) comes to the rescue here. Join rows with a space, join result with a carriage return, profit.

```
puts @image.map { |inner| inner.join ' ' }.join $/
#⇒ 0 0 0 0
#  0 1 0 0
#  0 0 0 1
#  0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am going to review array doc again. Join method was one of the few methods I missed out